# How to create multiple queries in a single GET request

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-pg-pool

I am using `node-pg` and would like to make multiple queries within a single `GET` request.

For example consider I make two queries like so:

```
const getSomeInfo = (request, response) => {
    
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM jobs', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        var jobObj = results.rows;
        response.render('pages/jobinfo', {
            jobObj: jobObj
        });
    })

    pool.query('SELECT * FROM description INNER JOIN views', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        var descObj = results.rows;
        response.render('pages/jobinfo', {
            descObj: descObj
        });
    })
    
}
```

This code results in the following error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

Is there a way to make both these queries within the same `GET` request so that the objects containing the results can be used on the same page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render only *one* document, but this can contain *two* local variables, one from each query. To have the queries executed in parallel, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and make use of the fact that `pool.query` without a callback function returns a promise.

```js
const getSomeInfo = (request, response) => {
    
  Promise.all([
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM jobs'),
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM description INNER JOIN views')
  ]).then(function([jobResults, descResults]) {
    response.render('pages/jobinfo', {
      jobObj: jobResults.rows,
      descObj: descResults.rows
    });
  }, function(error) {
    throw error;
  });
    
}
```