# async.parallel for app.use with second parameter

Tags: javascript, express, async.js

I use [express v4.17.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and would like to make my app.use() middlewares to run in parallel.

So I have found some examples in the internet.

**Example:**

```js
function runInParallel() {
  async.parallel([
    getUserProfile,
    getRecentActivity,
    getSubscriptions,
    getNotifications
  ], function(err, results) {
    //This callback runs when all the functions complete
  });
}
```

But what I have in my application is:

```js
const app = express();
const APP_FOLDER = "bdt";

app.use(httpContext.middleware);
app.use(metricsMiddleware);
app.use(rtEndMiddleware);
app.use(trackingContextMiddleware);
app.use(healthRoutes());

app.use("/" + APP_FOLDER + "/api/products", productsRoutes);
app.use("/tcalc/" + APP_FOLDER + "/api/products", productsRoutes);
```

productRoutes is this:

```js
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json({
  limit: "1mb",
});

const accessFilter = accessFilterMiddleware(Registry.list());
const localDevFilter = localDevFilterMiddleware(Registry.list());

const apiRoutes: Router = Router();


apiRoutes.get("/", listProducts);
apiRoutes.get("/healthz", cProductHealth);
apiRoutes.get("/:id", accessFilter, localDevFilter, fetchProductData);
apiRoutes.post(
  "/:id",
  accessFilter,
  localDevFilter,
  jsonParser,
  fetchProductData,
);
apiRoutes.get(
  "/:id/fields/:fieldId/options",
  accessFilter,
  localDevFilter,
  fetchProductOptions,
);
apiRoutes.post(
  "/:id/loadmoreoptions",
  accessFilter,
  localDevFilter,
  jsonParser,
  loadMoreOptions,
);
apiRoutes.post("/:id/ploy", accessFilter, jsonParser, fetchMultipleProductData);
apiRoutes.post(
  "/:id/gxx",
  accessFilter,
  localDevFilter,
  jsonParser,
  fetchGssData,
);
apiRoutes.get("/:id/healthz", collectProductHealth);
```

I think for the first ones it should be easy:

```js
async.parallel([
  httpContext.middleware,
  metricsMiddleware,
  rtEndMiddleware,
  trackingContextMiddleware,
  healthRoutes()
], function(err, results) {
  //This callback runs when all the functions complete
});
```

But my question: How can I do it with a second parameter (productRoutes) in this case ?

```js
app.use("/" + APP_FOLDER + "/api/products", productsRoutes);
app.use("/tcalc/" + APP_FOLDER + "/api/products", productsRoutes);
```

Comment: _"would like to make my routes run in parallel"_ explain this please

Comment: why not create one route and use promise all to get results from multiple services. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#awaiting_a_promise.all

Comment: The four middlewares that you want to run in parallel must somehow collaborate to produce *one* response `res` for each incoming request `req`. Can you explain how their collaboration shall work? For example, each middleware could contribute some HTML, but that would end up in random order in the overall response.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68805408/16462950.

Comment: I have updated my question to be more precise. @HeikoTheißen

Comment: I don't understand. What is `productsRoutes`? And what has it got to do with parallelism?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I have provided productRoutes in my first post here as well.

What I am referring to is this article:
https://www.gosquared.com/blog/making-dashboard-faster

See Step 1. There they descríbe a performance boost from 10 seconds down to 1.5 seconds by running the middleware in parallel

Comment: But the performance gain is not because the middleware functions are parallelized. It is only because *external* operations (like DB access, or outbound HTTP requests) are parallelized. And this can be done like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68805408/16462950).

Comment: The native Promisr.all([]); performs way better than async parallel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Middleware in Concept

As far as I understand it, middleware is akin to a chain, where each middleware item:

- performs some initial logic
- calls the next link in the chain, then
- performs some final logic

where both of the chunks of logic are optional, but calling the next link is not. For example, with your first set of middleware, through to `healthRoutes()`, it could be visualised like so:

```
> httpContext.middleware

  > metricsMiddleware

    > rtEndMiddleware

      > trackingContextMiddleware

        /healthRoutes

      < trackingContextMiddleware

    < rtEndMiddleware

  < metricsMiddleware

< httpContext.middleware
```

This chain structure is generally used because each middleware may enhance the common state of the request, sometimes conditionally based on the "output" of previously executed middlewares, and for many middlewares the initial logic needs to be performed before the body of the request, and the final logic after.

#### Middleware - Parallelisable or Not?

Based on the parallelisation in the blog post, the previously separate middlewares (`getUser`, `getSiteList`, `getCurrentSite` and `getSubscription`) very likely operate independently, which, in my opinion, makes them quite poor candidates for use as middleware. It's no wonder that they observed a significant performance improvement, as these items *should never have been run in series in the first place*. If we employ the same `parallel()` function from the post (note, specifically that function, not `async.parallel`), for the same middlewares as above, the execution looks more like:

```
> httpContext.middleware

< httpContext.middleware

> metricsMiddleware

< metricsMiddleware

> rtEndMiddleware

< rtEndMiddleware

> trackingContextMiddleware

< trackingContextMiddleware

/healthRoutes
```

So, parallelising the middlewares changes the order of execution significantly. Only you can determine whether this would be acceptable for your application, but I can imagine that both `metricsMiddleware` and `trackingContextMiddleware` may need to perform some logic both before and after the request being executed.

#### Express Route Syntax

If you decide that you do want to parallelise some or all of the middleware, I'd suggest taking advantage of native `Promise`s directly, not a separate library, and do something like:

```
const parallel = (...middlewares) => (req, res, next) => {
  Promise.all(middlewares.map(x => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    x(req, res, resolve);
  }))).then(() => next());
}
```

The important parts of this function are:

- returning a function that takes the `req`, `res`, and `next` arguments, satisfying the requirement of Express middleware, that

  - maps each middleware to a `Promise` that executes the middleware and is passed the `resolve` argument of the `Promise` callback as its `next` argument
  - gates all these `Promise`s behind `Promise.all`, and finally
  - calls the externally provided `next` argument when that gated `Promise` resolves

Then, if you decided that you wanted to have `httpContent.middleware` and `metricsMiddleware` run in parallel, but the others in series, you'd use that like:

```
app.use(parallel(
  httpContext.middleware,
  metricsMiddleware
));
app.use(rtEndMiddleware);
app.use(trackingContextMiddleware);
app.use(healthRoutes());
```

the execution of which could be visualised as:

```
> httpContext.middleware

< httpContext.middleware

> metricsMiddleware

< metricsMiddleware

> rtEndMiddleware

  > trackingContextMiddleware

    /healthRoutes

  < trackingContextMiddleware

< rtEndMiddleware
```

As for the remaining two `app.use()` statements, given that each subsequent `app.use()` will add an item onto the middleware stack, you basically don't have to do anything to parallelise all the middleware up to that point, and if I were going down this path, I would keep the middleware explicitly separate (whether used in parallel or series) from the route implementations themselves, to make it clear where the specific application logic begins.

Answer (score 2):

You've been going down a rabbit hole and you should change your approach quite a bit, currently you're completely over complicating a simple problem and the solution you're looking for is not possible in javascript.

If you want to create routes in express then don't use `app.use` for everything, it should only be used for middleware or to register a router, on which you can define routes.

You should be using:

```
app.get('/', () => ...
```

To define your routes.  Alternatively you can use a router for that as well by doing:

```
app.use(router)

...

router.get('/', () => ...
```

More than that if you want to define `async` or "parallel" routes in javascript then just define async callbacks like normal, remove most of the stuff you've done.

```
app.get('/', async () => ...
```

That is now a route that will execute asynchronously.

You should also be careful not to just mess around with express' middleware because you're going to mess up the existing middleware (like error routes).

What's more is that the library you're referring to is just a helper library with neat functionality, it won't fundamentally change how javascript works. When you call an async function it will be added to the event queue and still be executed synchronously one after the other in serial, true multi threading isn't possible except for service workers and browser API calls executing temporarily in a single thread of their own, before being added to the event queue anyways.

What you're looking for is just a simple: `router.get('/', async () => ...`, that's the best you can do and it will appear that all your routes are executing in parallel.

After you've declared multiple of those then you can invoke all of them with something like `Promise.all`.  My best guess is that this is what something like `parallel` is doing as well.

Comment: `That is now a route that will execute asynchronously.` - that change (adding `async` by itself) does very little when both a) there are no uses of `await` in the function and b) the function already operates in a continuation passing style (as do Express routes, via the `res` argument).

Comment: @msbit I have updated my question to be more precise, could you please have a look ?

Comment: @Gutelaunetyp as I had mentioned in my answer, you won't ever be able to get your routes to be truly parallel, unless that library is passing requests down into kernal and creeating actual threads for it, which I doubt.  Even if your library is making all routes async, it will still be added to the event queue and you'll just be moving your serial execution from one place to another.

Comment: @Matriarx correct. But on this page here:

https://www.gosquared.com/blog/making-dashboard-faster

in Step 1 the guy claims a performance boost from 10 seconds down to 1.5 seconds, which seems to be incredibly big boost. That is actually why I am asking

Comment: It's not possible to get a backend request in express 10x faster, express is already serving requests in under 10ms.  That blog is showing performance for caching, frontend resources and other things, those are the things that improves performance.  You're trying to optimize in the wrong place.

Comment: If you want your stuff to be really parallel then use nginx as a bypass like you'll be using it in production some day, then it will be genuine multi threaded requests.  You won't achieve what you want in express.