# Creating a query that relies on results of previous query using node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-postgres

The first query to the postgres database is a `SELECT` query gets all shift/break data for the current day which is used to determine the type of scan

The second query is an `INSERT` query that is dependent on the results of the first query

My handler function looks like this right now:

```
const scanEvent = (request, response) => {
   employee_id = request.body.employee_id;
   var shifts;
   Promise.all([
      pool.query('Select * FROM shifts WHERE employee_id=$1 AND date=CURRENT_DATE', [employee_id])
   ]).then(function([queryResults]) {
      shifts = queryResults.rows;
   }).catch(function(e) {
      response.status(500).send('Error retrieving data');
   })
   // based on the results of the query there will be a bunch of different cases for
   // INSERT queries to put in the proper data to the database
   if(shifts.length == 0) {
      Promise.all([
         pool.query('INSERT INTO shifts (employee_id, start_time) VALUES ($1, NOW())', [employee_id])
      ]).then(function() {
         response.status(204).send('Successfully Inserted');
      }).catch(function (e) {
         response.status(500).send("Error");
      });
    } // else if ... handle all other cases
}
```

My issue is that I cannot access the results of the first query as it seems that the `shifts` variable is local in scope to the first `Promise.all`

## `** EDIT **`

I have now realized my approach was not optimal (was just learning node-postgres) A better way to solve this problem is to use async / await:

```
const scanEvent = async (request, response) => {
   employee_id = request.body.employee_id;
   var shifts;

   const getShifts = await pool.query('Select * FROM shifts WHERE employee_id=$1 AND date=CURRENT_DATE', [employee_id]);

   shifts = getShifts.rows;

   // based on the results of the query there will be a bunch of different cases for
   // INSERT queries to put in the proper data to the database
   if(shifts.length == 0) {
      await pool.query('INSERT INTO shifts (employee_id, start_time) VALUES ($1, NOW())', [employee_id]);

    } // else if ... handle all other cases
}
```

Comment: Why do you use Promise.all with just one Promise?

Comment: @madflow I have realized now that using the Promise.all with just one Promise is pointless, when I was learning node-postgres that's just how I saw queries being made so that's how I did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `shifts` will *not yet* have a value when the `if` statement is executed, because it receives its value only in the `.then` function. Therefore, if the second half or your code relies on the value of `shifts`, move it into the `.then` function:

```
.then(function([queryResults]) {
  shifts = queryResults.rows;
  if(/* first scan therefore scanning in for shift */) {
    ...
  } // else if ... handle all other cases
})
```

(If you want two independent queries executed in parallel, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68805408/16462950).)