# Getting data from two seperate collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get data from two separate collections and sending them over to .hbs
I understand how to get the data from one collection, but I'm having trouble with the second one.

```js
const KillLogs = require('../models/MurderLogs');
const RobberyLogs = require('../models/RobberyLogs');

//It gets data from KillLogs and it works perfectly fine, but I don't know how to get data from RobberyLogs as well and save it to "logsData" so it can be transferred over to .hbs, I am not sure if there is another way of doing this but this is my way, please feel free to correct me or give me advices
router.get('/', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    let logsResult = await KillLogs.find({}).lean().exec((err, logsData) => {
        if(logsData) {
            res.render("index", { title: "Home", data:logsData});
        }
    })
});
```

As you can see in the code it gets data from "KillLogs" but how can I get data from "KillLogs and RobberyLogs"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create multiple queries in a single GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68804781/how-to-create-multiple-queries-in-a-single-get-request)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using MySQL, I'm using MongoDB

Comment: But the way in which you can use `Promise.all` is the same.